# Call scalar function in CASE expression SQL Server 2012+

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to emulate the PL/SQL `DECODE()` function in T-SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDecode]
(
    @condition     AS BIT,
    @trueVal       AS VARCHAR(2000),
    @falseVal      AS VARCHAR(2000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @condition
                WHEN 1 THEN @trueVal
                ELSE @falseVal
           END
END
GO
```

The PL/SQL fragment I'm trying to port to T-SQL is this:

```
CASE pcr.person_type
WHEN 'N'
THEN
      npcr.first_name
   || DECODE (npcr.middle_name,
              NULL, '',
              ' ' || npcr.middle_name)
   || ' '
   || npcr.last_name
WHEN 'L'
THEN
   lpcr.name
END
```

I want to call the scalar function defined above in a `CASE` statement like this:

```
CASE pcr.person_type
  WHEN 'N' THEN npcr.first_name
      + dbo.fnDecode(npcr.middle_name IS NULL, '', ' ' + npcr.middle_name)
      + ' '
      + npcr.last_name
  WHEN 'L' THEN lpcr.name
END
```

I cannot store the result of the `fnDecode()` function into a variable because the rows are coming from some joined tables (and there are multiple calls to `fnDecode()` in the queries I'm porting)

We're using SQL Server 2012 and 2014.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (It has a return value.)

Comment: why not a `case statement ` instead of `dbo.fnDecode`?

Comment: @Praveen I've been doing exactly that till now but it looks messy (there are 4-5 such fragments in many of the pl-sql sprocs). These pl/sql stored procs are quite complicated and large (some are more than 500+ lines long) and I'm trying to write succinct T-SQL code.

Comment: You appear to be re-implementing [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx). Why?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your tip has solved my immediate problem! Though the original question (is it possible to call scalar function in a case statement) still remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porting procedural approaches *"as it is"* is not a good practice at all. This is not a PHP, C# or even PL/SQL. Furthermore, in the case described you don't even need any function calls. `NULL` and empty string handling in scenarios mentioned above is very simple and does not require any procedural methods.

There are functions `NULLIF`, `ISNULL`, `COALESCE`, `CASE` statement. Everything you need is to check if something is `true` or `false`, `null` or not.

Scalar UDF calls for every row may (and will) result in serious performance issues.

Check this out:

```
CASE pcr.person_type
  WHEN 'N' THEN npcr.first_name
      + IsNull(' ' + npcr.middle_name, '')
      + ' '
      + npcr.last_name
  WHEN 'L' THEN lpcr.name
END
```

even if you have disabled ANSI_NULLS and CONCAT_NULL_YIELD_NULL options and dont' wish to give any chance to server to do anything wrong you can use `case` and this approach will be much better than calling a function:

```
CASE pcr.person_type
  WHEN 'N' THEN npcr.first_name
      + case when npcr.middle_name is NULL then '' else ' ' + npcr.middle_name end
      + ' '
      + npcr.last_name
  WHEN 'L' THEN lpcr.name
END
```

if there are empty stings allowed this code can work well (with regular null option set):

```
CASE pcr.person_type
  WHEN 'N' THEN npcr.first_name
      + IsNull(' ' + NullIf(npcr.middle_name, ''), '')
      + IsNull(' ' + NullIf(npcr.last_name, ''), '')
  WHEN 'L' THEN lpcr.name
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible to call scalar functions from within `CASE` expressions (and many other places).

The issue you're experiencing relates to the first parameter. `BIT` is a numeric data type. Not a `boolean` and, in fact, SQL Server does not have an exposed `boolean` data type in T-SQL. So you cannot make the first parameter of your `fDecode` function a boolean, nor can you pass the result of evaluating a predicate, such as `npcr.middle_name = NULL` in a place that expects to accept a `bit`.

Something like *this* should execute:

```
CASE pcr.person_type
  WHEN 'N' THEN npcr.first_name
      + dbo.fnDecode(CASE WHEN npcr.middle_name = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, '', ' ' + npcr.middle_name)
      + ' '
      + npcr.last_name
  WHEN 'L' THEN lpcr.name
END
```

(Although you may also need to insert an explicit cast also)

But this makes the cure look worse than the curse.

In any case, you can just use the built in [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx) function rather than `fDecode`. Because it's built in, it doesn't play by the same rules that you have to play by, and in fact *its* first parameter is a boolean expression.